# Can't get commas to seperate my CSV values

Tags: python, csv

I got the file to print in a vertical column, however, the values still need to be separated using commas and here is what the output looks like right now.

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Here is the code that outputs the text to the CSV files.

```
with open("all_labels", "w") as outputFile:
    writer1 = csv.writer(outputFile, lineterminator='\n')
    for item in allArray:
        writer1.writerow([item])


with open("odd_labels", "w") as outputFile1:
    writer2 = csv.writer(outputFile1, lineterminator='\n')
    for item in oddArray:
        writer2.writerow([item])

with open("even_labels", "w") as outputFile2:
    writer3 = csv.writer(outputFile2, lineterminator='\n')
    for item in evenArray:
        writer3.writerow([item])
```

and I just need help to add in the commas back to the file if anybody has any suggestions so that the final output in the file will read.

1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,

Comment: Remove `lineterminator='\n'` I'm not sure you need it

Comment: you could also just use a string writer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file

Comment: @coldspeed I need that because otherwise there would be spaces between each value like an indent

Comment: Change all the `writerow()` from `writer3.writerow([item])` to `writer3.writerow([item,''])`.

Comment: An existing method specifically for this could be an easier approach - numpy.savetxt or pandas' to_csv, for example.

Comment: @alvits that worked thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you need to do this? CSV files just use comma as separators, there's no comma needed at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an extra separator, you can write a list with an extra, empty element in it:

```
writer3.writerow([item, ''])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like below

```
evenArray = [1,2,3,4]

for item in evenArray:
        print(str(item)+',' )
```

Output

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
```

so you can use

```
writer2.writerow(str(item)+',')
```

Comment: That will iterate through each character. The 10th line will be `1,0,","`. And everything above it will be `X,","` where X is from 1 to 9. Not exactly what the OP wanted. As a note, `print()` and `writerow()` don't behave the same.

Comment: evenArray = ["hello",2,3,4]

for item in evenArray:
        print(str(item)+',' )
        
output : hello,
2,
3,
4,

Comment: Only `print()` will do that. `writerow()` won't. Try it.

Comment: @alvits  thanks you are right ..but char can be converted to string

Comment: Saying _so you can use_  **`writer2.writerow(str(item)+',')`** is reckless.

Comment: Again you are telling the OP to write `1,0,","` and `X,","` is plain wrong. Try to suggest something that actually works.